# How to show popup after user connect to my WiFi hotspot?

Tags: wifi, desktop-environment, broadcast

So we know we can use `create New WiFi network` option under wifi menu in Linux desktop to broadcast the WiFi out with custom name&passowrd like the picture below

But is it possible to throw a popup to user when the connection established (first time)? Like what free wifi do, popup a page which require you enter login credential or click ad before you got internet access.

If yes, how?

Comment: Your talking about a captive portal, a quick google for opensource captive portal projects returns wifidog and chillispot, not sure if these will be overkill for what you want.

Comment: ChilliSpot – http://www.chillispot.info
Opennac – http://www.opennac.org
Wifidog – http://dev.wifidog.org
PacketFence – http://www.packetfence.org
CoovaChilli – http://coova.org
Utangle – http://www.untangle.com
pfSense – http://www.pfsense.org
PepperSpot – http://pepperspot.sourceforge.net
Zeroshell – http://www.zeroshell.net/eng/
m0n0wall – http://m0n0.ch
Kattive – http://www.kattive.it
EasyHotSpot – http://easyhotspot.inov.asia/
GRASE Hotspot – http://grasehotspot.org
BrazilFW – http://www.brazilfw.com.br
Alcasar – http://www.alcasar.net/en